# Error using sql statement in Android Room:SQL error or missing database (no such column:xx)

Tags: android-room

I used the following statement in mysql to query the data successfully：
"`` SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `im_msg_hist` ORDER BY dTime DESC) AS T where toId='xxxx' or frmId='xxxx' GROUP BY toId ``".

but when i using such a statement in Android Room gives an error:"`There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: tb_msg.id)`"
this is Entity :

```
@Entity(tableName = "tb_msg")
public class Message {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "send_id")
    private String sendId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "receive_id")
    private String receiveId;

    ...
}
```

this is dao:

```
@Dao
public interface MessageDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tb_msg ORDER BY time DESC) AS T WHERE send_id=:userId or receive_id=:userId GROUP BY send_id")
    LiveData<List<PersonalMsg>> getGroupByReceiveId(String userId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify table name columns name for room. I suggest you to refer [this doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/package-summary)

```
Entity(tableName = "tb_msg")
public class Message {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "send_id")
    private String sendId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "receive_id")
    private String receiveId;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, not for this reason

Comment: did "Entity(tableName = "tb_msg")" not solve your problem?

Comment: I have this in my code, I forgot to write it in the above description.
`@Query("SELECT * FROM tb_msg ORDER BY time DESC")` is ok 
`@Query("SELECT * FROM tb_msg WHERE send_id=:userId or receive_id=:userId GROUP BY send_id")` also ok
but when two statements are combined `@Query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tb_msg ORDER BY time DESC) AS T WHERE send_id=:userId or receive_id=:userId GROUP BY send_id")` there is above error